# Working with NaN values in multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have multiple datasets with different number of rows and same number of columns.
I would like to find Nan values in each column for example consider these two datasets:

```
dataset1 :            dataset2:
a  b                  a    b
1  10                 2    11
2  9                  3    12
3  8                  4    13
4  nan                nan  14
5  nan                nan  15
6  nan                nan  16
```

I want to find nan values in two datasets a and b :
if it occurs in column b  then remove all the rows that have nan values. and if it occurs in column a then fill that values with 0.

this is my snippet code:

```
a=pd.notnull(data['a'].values.any())
b= pd.notnull((data['b'].values.any()))
if a:
     data = data.dropna(subset=['a'])
if b:
     data[['a']] = data[['a']].fillna(value=0)
```

which does not work properly.

Comment: FWIW: its recommended to use `pd.notna` instead of `notnull` because `notnull` doesn't capture all variations of nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your condition to a dict

```
df=df.fillna({'a':0,'b':np.nan}).dropna()
```

You do not need 'b' here

```
df=df.fillna({'a':0}).dropna()
```

EDIT :

```
df.fillna({'a':0}).dropna()
Out[1319]: 
     a   b
0  2.0  11
1  3.0  12
2  4.0  13
3  0.0  14
4  0.0  15
5  0.0  16
```

Comment: Still have nan values in column b

Comment: @AlterNative you can only choose one as the accepted answer (-:

Comment: You don't need the `'b'` key at all.  `df.fillna({'a': 0}).dropna()`

Comment: it does not work on my second dataset. It removes all the rows, I need to keep them and set the values for the rows in column a to 0.

Comment: @Wen I should try again. thanks I do not know why it does not give me the right answer in my real dataset

Comment: @AlterNative have nice day :-)

Answer (score 4):

You just need fillna and dropna without control flow

```
data = data.dropna(subset=['b']).fillna(0)
```